# How do the cockpit controls of a tiltrotor aircraft work?

Tags: flight-controls, cockpit, powered-lift, tiltrotor

I'm having trouble trying to imagine the primary flight controls in the cockpit of a [tiltrotor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiltrotor) aircraft - how would one design it?

In an airplane, turning the wheel to the left would always deflect the ailerons (even when the plane is stationary!), while in a helicopter moving the stick to the left would always tilt the rotor disc. However in a tiltrotor neither is true - not to mention, we need to control the aircraft when it is transitioning between hover and cruising state!

So, just exactly how does one pilot a tiltrotor aircraft?

Comment: With a bit of practice.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[This video explains it nicely](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dmUkCNlj7rY) starting at about 1:20 in.

[Also see here](https://www.quora.com/How-exactly-do-the-V-22-Ospreys-control-surfaces-work).

This is a [pretty interesting article on flying it](https://www.verticalmag.com/features/20112-flying-the-v-22-html/) as well. It really seems to depend on mode but its summarized here nicely,

> Climbing into the front seats of the Osprey definitely does not
>   produce the most graceful entrance: it requires some contorting around
>   the armrest, center console and overhead panel. The cockpit is
>   dominated by four night-vision-goggle-compatible, six-inch-square
>   multi-function displays that allow access to flight, navigation and
>   system information. Mechanical flight controls consist of a center
>   control stick, thrust control lever (TCL) and rudder pedals. The
>   control stick functions as cyclic control while in conversion and
>   helicopter modes, but steadily fades into a traditional airplane
>   control stick as the nacelles transition to airplane mode.
>
> The TCL
>   moves fore and aft just like an airplane throttle, unlike a helicopter
>   collective. It does operate as a collective control, however, and
>   becomes a traditional throttle during the transition. While this may
>   seem counter-intuitive to helicopter pilots, it actually makes a lot
>   of sense, because regardless of the mode of flight, youre always doing
>   the same thing: controlling the thrust vector. Forward on the TCL in
>   helicopter mode is the same as raising the collective in a helicopter,
>   and vice versa. The first couple of hours for helicopter pilots
>   transitioning to the Osprey highlight a bit of collective dyslexia,
>   but very quickly it never becomes a further problem. A spring-loaded,
>   knurled rotary knob on the TCL that lies in contact with the pilots
>   left thumb controls the nacelles. Roll the thumbwheel aft and the
>   nacelles rotate to the vertical, roll it forward and the nacelles
>   continue to the downstops. The controls follow the hands on throttle
>   and stick, or HOTAS, concept, and have all the controls necessary on
>   them to control multiple systems on the airplane.